# Shutting down gracefully the app when a signal is received

Tags: java, signals, shutdown

I'm thinking how to write a signal handler that would inform the main thread about the need to exit.

What I'm thinking is:

1) use the following code to intercept the signal

```
SignalHandler handler = new SignalHandler () {
      public void handle(Signal sig) {
        System.out.println("Signal " + sig);
        System.out.println("Shutting down...");

        ServiceLocator.ProgramState().setMustExit();

        System.exit(0);
      }
    };
Signal.handle(new Signal("INT"), handler);
Signal.handle(new Signal("TERM"), handler);
```

2) Set a ProgramState object to indicate the need to exit: ServiceLocator.ProgramState().setMustExit();

3) put the following code in some parts of the program to check if ProgramState tells me to exit:

```
if (ServiceLocator.ProgramState().mustExit()) {
    throw new MustExitException();
}
```

the exception would be intecepted by the main thread which would exit cleanly.

I don't like very much throwing an exception like I'm going to do, but this seems a quick way to achieve my goal.

Are there any other ways to exit gracefully?

Answer (score 1):

The main thread usually waits for some event/notification (either directly or indirectly) that prevents it from terminating the program immediately

A clean shutdown would be letting the main thread know it's time to "move-on" either by interrupting it or by notifying it. As part of path to end the program execution beyond that point, it should take care of "terminating" other crucial parts of the program (in most of the cases, there aren't any).

If the application is single threaded... well it probably shouldn't be. The core execution logic should be separated from the main thread.

Spring IOC / Guice (Netflix governator) exist especially to achieve better life cycle-control over your object-graph.

Both can aid you in building an implementation where the bootstrap/shutdown/component wiring is decoupled from the actual logic of the application and provide convenient way of managing the life-cycle of your various objects/classes.

I wholeheartedly recommend that you'll use them instead of rolling your own shutdown mechanism. (Keeping the signal handling functionality, of course, but that should also be decoupled from the main thread). You'll eventually wind up with a poison-pill like mechanism.

For example - if you choose to work with Spring, you'll define the signal handler as a bean, inject/autowire it with the `ConfigurableApplicationContext` instance, and call its `close()` method upon receiving the desired signal. That'll cause all spring wired beans to perform their defined (if defined) shutdown/destruction behavior

P.S. signal handling will work, but there are more concrete ways to convey shutdown messages (see ZeroMq/JeroMQ, for a brokerless message example) from external sources.